# How do I make PivotItems in Pivot wrap around like a WrapPanel?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to have the PivotItems in my Pivot to wrap around when the items exceed the App width much like a WrapPanel instead of the default scrolling. I tried setting up the Pivot.ItemTemplate as shown below but that didnt work. Thanks in advance.

```
            <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:WrapPanel />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many design mechanisms inside the HeaderTemplate of NavigationView and Pivot. It is very difficult to change it. But we could achieve a similar  effect through layout. You could add a wrapPanel, then add controls inside the panel and use Frame to navigate to another page. As follows:

```
<StackPanel >
 <wrap:WrapPanel x:Name="Itemgrid"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
     //add your control to show header
 </wrap:WrapPanel >
 <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
</StackPanel>
```